# Determining if $u''+(u^2+u'{^2}-1)u'+u=0$ has a limit cycle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

> I am trying to determine if the ODE $$u''+(u^2+u'{^2}-1)u'+u=0,$$ has a limit cycle.

Converting this ODE into a system of first-order ODES,
$$\underline{x}=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}, \ \  \underline{x}'=\begin{pmatrix}
y \\
-y(x^2+y^2-1)-x \end{pmatrix}.$$ Using polar coordinates, we can show that $$r'=-r\sin^2(\theta)(r^2-1).$$
Clearly, $r'=0$ when $r=0,1$ and when $\theta=n\pi\ $ for $\ n\in\mathbb{Z}.$
I have been instructed that $r=0$ is a fixed point, my question is **why**?
From my understanding, a fixed point was such that $r'=0$ and $\theta'=0$, but the equation for $\theta'$ is
$$\theta'=-1-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(r^2-1).$$ For $r=0$, $\theta'\neq 0.$

Comment: Putting $r=0$ into the equation, then you have $0=0$. So $r=0$ is an equilibrium point.

Comment: @xpaul Thanks. But if this is the case, how can we make any assumptions on $r=1$. It is given that this is a periodic solution.

Comment: Do you still want the result for the equilibrium $r=1$ which is a limit cycle?

Comment: @xpaul Yes please, that would be fantastic

Comment: What  is needed is to use the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polar coordinates are $u=r\cosθ$, $u'=r\sinθ$. Thus if $r=0$ and stays there, you get $(u,u')=(0,0)$ for all times, a fixed, stationary or equilibrium point.

Comment: Ah I see. Does this mean then that by default $r=1$ must be our periodic solution? I agree that $r=0$ represents a fixed point, but how do we know that $r=1$ represents a periodic solution?

Comment: Yes, in this case everything plays well together so that indeed $u(t)=\cos t$ is a solution.

Comment: Is $r=0$ the only fixed point for these kinds of question (using the transformation to polar coordinates)?

Comment: Not necessarily, you will always have to check for other stationary points, as they invalidate Poincaré-Bendixson style arguments. Setting $u''=0=u'$ in the original equation gives $u=0$ as only possibility, so no, here in this example there are no other stationary points.

Comment: Yep, I understand. If the equation for $r'$ is independent of theta, does this mean that the solutions to $r'=0$ are fixed points?

Comment: No, that just means that you have solutions contained in the circle with radius $r$. If that radius is positive, you also need a constant angle for a fixed point.

Comment: Ah of course! For instance, if we found that $r=1$ and $\theta'=-1$, this would be a fixed point (i.e. the condition that $r$ is positive and theta is unchanging implies a fixed point)?

Comment: No, that would be a periodic solution. If at $θ=-\frac\pi3$ you were to get $θ'=0$, then that would be stationary.

Comment: Do you recommend any textbooks or sources that outline some of these results?

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two closed cycles $r=\frac12$ and $r=\frac32$, respectively. Let $R$ be the region between $C_1$ and $C_2$. At $C_1$,
$$ r'\bigg|_{r=\frac12}=-r\sin^2(\theta)(r^2-1)\bigg|_{r=\frac12}\ge0 $$
which means that $r(t)$ points toward the interior of $R$ at each point of $C_1$. Similarly, $r(t)$ points toward the interior of $R$ at each point of $C_2$. By the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem, there is a limit cycle lying inside of $R$. Actually, the limit cycle is $r=1$ since it is an equilibrium point.

Comment: Thank you for this great response. I have made another post on a similar question, I'd encourage you to take a look :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297492/how-do-we-know-r-0-is-a-fixed-point